# Get user ID when action row link is clicked

Tags: users, wp-list-table, row-actions

I have added an action row link to users.php so that when its clicked it links to a list table.

To generate the data for the clicked user in my custom list table, I need to capture the user ID.

I have all the code working but I don't know how to access the user ID of the user that was clicked.

I am passing the user ID as user via the link so its show in my custom list table url. For example, admin.php?page=history_logger&user=3.

http://screencast.com/t/ImZgcCUaR this might help.

Comment: Can you add the code that you have for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am passing the user ID as user via the link so its show in my custom list table url. For example, admin.php?page=history_logger&user=3

The user ID is in the query variable. You can access it using a PHP global variable. `$_GET['user']`

```
$user_id = $_GET['user'];
```

Do not assume that this request (link) came from the Users Page. You should validate `$user_id` to be certain it is an integer and a valid user id before operating on it.